# ROR action-text. How to add text-align options to trix rich-text editor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trix, actiontext

Im working on a project in ruby on rails (rails 6), that include a blog working with action-text and trix. I have to add few option to my rich-text editor and there is one that block me for few days.

I added buttons in my trix toolbar, for add more title tag options following [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58805984/add-buttons-to-rails-actiontext-toolbar) and everything worked fine.

But when i try to add text-align options (left, right, center) it dont work

I tried many thing, but i would expect this to work:

in application.js

```
Trix.config.textAttributes.alignLeft = {
style: { textAlign: "left" },
parser: function(element) {
    return element.style.alignLeft === "left"
},
inheritable: true
```

}

then i insert it in the toolbar like this:
in application.js also

```
addEventListener("trix-initialize", function(event) {
var buttonHTML = '<button type="button" data-trix-attribute="alignLeft">RED</button>'

event.target.toolbarElement.
querySelector(".trix-button-group").
insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", buttonHTML)
```

})

I tried both, with blockAttributes and textAttributes but dont work.
The button appear but does nothing.
What i want is that the div where my text is embed get style=" text-align: left"

Do you have an idea of how i could make it work? or maybe ideas, advices or lectures propositions?

(i saw somes issues in basecamp/trix github that speak about that([this one](https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/289) is really interesting), but its appear that the customized tag option, is not a good option and i didnt managed to make anything else work.

Thanks a lot

Comment: In this fiddle, one of the trix devs shows some ways to do conditional logic and add buttons etc.  could this help?  you could toggle right-align class ?   Let me know how it goes.  customizing trix is hard! https://jsfiddle.net/javan/z66gzbcp/3/

Answer (score 1):

you can see this [enter link description here](https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/985)

insert some button like this, and multiple alignments cannot exist in the same paragraph of text, and you can see
[enter link description here](https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/985#issuecomment-1539677936)